# Breaking up rows into different columns and concatenating them in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2000+ rows that repeats this pattern:
[image]

What I need is something similar to this:

```
change_order  material   error_message
C601987       600099882  Invalid Model for Material, Invalid Material for Model
C601987       600099883  Invalid Model for Material, Invalid Material for Model
```

I've been able to get a data frame that is just the Change order and Material number, but I can't figure out how to combine the rows that start with invalid. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The requested information for reproducing the data.

```
structure(list(change_order = c("C601987", "C601987", "C601987", 
"C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987", 
"C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987", "C601987"
), error_message = c("Material:000000000600099882 - Component:000000000600134722: Error Message - E", 
"- Invalid Model for Material", "- Invalid Material for Model", 
"Material:000000000600099882 - Component:000000000600138896: Error Message - E", 
"- Invalid Model for Material", "- Invalid Material for Model", 
"Material:000000000600099882 - Component:000000000600134722: Error Message - E", 
"- Invalid Model for Material", "- Invalid Material for Model", 
"Material:000000000600099882 - Component:000000000600138896: Error Message - E", 
"- Invalid Model for Material", "- Invalid Material for Model", 
"Material:000000000600099883 - Component:000000000600134722: Error Message - E", 
"- Invalid Model for Material", "- Invalid Material for Model"
)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Is it always in sets of 3 like this, with 2 "- Invalid..." rows?

Comment: It's very difficult to test/demonstrate code on pictures of data. Would you please share data in a copy/pasteable way? `dput()` is the best way to do this, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:15, ])` for the first 15 rows. This is copy/pasteable and preserves all class and structure information.

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated the question, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to first split the values we need out into their own columns (material and error message). Once we have those parts in their own columns, we have the grouping variables necessary to aggregate to your desired summary. Note: if you need component broken out as well, you would essentially do the same thing that I demonstrate with Material.

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(stringr)

 data %>% 
    # separate material number into its own column, I coerce to numeric to trim the leading zeros
    mutate(material = as.numeric(gsub("^Material:(\\d+).*$", "\\1", error_message))) %>% 
    # pull the error messages into their own column
    mutate(Errors = ifelse(is.na(material), error_message, NA)) %>%
    group_by(change_order) %>%
    # fill the material ID down with the group so it can be matched with the Errors
    fill(material) %>% 
    distinct() %>% # if you care about components, don't use this line
    group_by(change_order, material) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Errors)) %>% 
    # concatenate the error messages into one row
    summarize(error_message = str_c(Errors, collapse = ", ")) %>%
    # clean up the dashes in the error messages
    mutate(error_message = gsub("- ", "", error_message, fixed = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   change_order [1]
  change_order  material error_message                                         
  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>                                                 
1 C601987      600099882 Invalid Model for Material, Invalid Material for Model
2 C601987      600099883 Invalid Model for Material, Invalid Material for Model
```